# Passing a value from listview to a textbox in another form C#

Tags: c#, sql, forms, listview

I have two forms as Main form and Product form. In the Main form I have a listview which contains the details of product. I want to sent the product id in the listview to the Product form through the 'Update' button click. Can any one help me? This is the code to bind the listview in the main form. And i have a textbox1 in Product form.

```
        public void BindGridProduct()
    {
    try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U1OP1S9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PaintStores;Integrated Security=True");

            SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "sp_getAllProducts";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dataTable);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow drow = dataTable.Rows[i];

                // Only row that have not been deleted
                if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                {
                    // Define the list items
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["ProductId"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["ProductName"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["TypeName"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Quantity"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Price"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Stock"].ToString());


                    // Add the list items to the ListView
                    listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And this is the button in the Main form, to pass the value to other form

```
        private void button22_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //code

    }
```

Regards

Comment: Create a new constructor of your form which except the value you want. You can use this constructor to show this form.

Comment: A form is a class like every other: you can add a constructor accepting your parameters, or properties with getter and setter, or a method for setting and handling the value you need. There is nothing special with a Form about this, just do the same you would do with a class. Just be sure your product form has also a parameterless constructor (as the default one that visual studio generates for you): visual studio designer requires it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a constructor:

```
public partial class frmProduct : Form
    {
        public frmProduct()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public frmProduct(int yourId)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Show your form:

```
int id = 5;
frmProduct frm = new frmProduct(id);
frm.Show(this);
```

Comment: Beat me to it :P

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer and close the thread

Comment: True, I just wanted him to mark that this question has been answered :)